# Extracting reviews from Amazon using Java jsoup library

Tags: java, jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MXLQ5TM/").get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("TITLE "+title);


Element reviews = doc.getElementById("reviewsMedley");
System.out.println(" " + reviews.text());
```

Hey, I am working on data extraction using jsoup and extracting reviews from Amazon. This is my code, it gives me reviews from first page. How can I transform it to get reviews from all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my simple implementation of Amazon review crawler.

```
package com.mycompany.amazon.crawler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class AmazonCrawler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AmazonCrawler.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        int pageNumber = 1;

        while (true) {

            /*
            URL is changed after saving answer, change it to this: 
            https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-Touchscreen-Performance-Bluetooth/product-reviews/B01MXLQ5TM/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_ + pageNumber + ?reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber= + pageNumber
             */
            String url = "https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-Touchscreen-Performance-Bluetooth/product-reviews/B01MXLQ5TM/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_" + pageNumber + "?reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=" + pageNumber;

            LOG.info("Crawling URL: {}", url);

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements reviewElements = doc.select(".review");
            if (reviewElements == null || reviewElements.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            for (Element reviewElement : reviewElements) {

                Element titleElement = reviewElement.select(".review-title").first();
                if (titleElement == null) {
                    LOG.error("Title element is null");
                    continue;
                }
                String title = titleElement.text();

                Element textElement = reviewElement.select(".review-text").first();
                if (textElement == null) {
                    LOG.error("Text element is null");
                    continue;
                }
                String text = textElement.text();

                reviews.add(new Review(title, text));
            }

            pageNumber++;
        }

        LOG.info("Number of reviews: {}", reviews.size());

        for (Review review : reviews) {
            System.out.println(review.getTitle());
            System.out.println(review.getText());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    static class Review {

        private final String title;
        private final String text;

        public Review(String title, String text) {
            this.title = title;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Before run this code, change URL to the URL in comment. For some reason, URL in code block is changed after saving answer.

Comment: thank you so much Milan the code seems will work perfectly but as an absolute beginner i have coming through a simple issue from where i can download these two jar files                                                                     import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

Comment: Hi Saadi. It is not important for this example, but if you want it, add the following dependencies to your pom.xml file: log4j-core, log4j-api and log4j-slf4j-impl from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j

Comment: Or if you don't use Maven, download jar files [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/download.html).

Comment: Again thank you so much the code is working perfectly and gives me the number of reviews for all the subsequent pages , if you don't mind i want to ask you one more question is there  any method from which i can extract all the review's text (comments) from all  review pages of product   i will be very thankful for your help ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Code above obtains all reviews from all pages. But i see, it obtains only "Verified Purchases" (on product page you can see for example "Showing 1-10 of 67 reviews(Verified Purchases). See all 70 reviews"). So I changed URL and now code above returns all 70 reviews.

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience Milan but what i m trying to explain is         "Element reviews = doc.getElementById("reviewsMedley");
System.out.println(" " + reviews.text());"                                                                       when i right this code it gives me output like this          "4.0 out of 5 stars Great for the cost. ByReeseon December 14, 2016 "    but only from first page of reviews but  when i run your code it only gives me the number of reviews from all pages like "67" i want reviews from all pages in text like i mentioned please help thanks :)

Comment: Your code gives you text from div with id "reviewsMedley". This is not good way to get all customer reviews because you get plain text without any structure. Also if you look on your result, you can see, that it contains also text like "Was this review helpful to you?YesNoReport" - this is in you result for each user review! Better way is define Review class, which contains for example review title and text.

Comment: By the way, my code will not give you only the number of reviews, it will give you all reviews from all pages as list of Review objects. It is so much better than simple plain text, because if you want to get for example text of the second user review, you can just call reviews.get(1).getText().

Comment: Thank you so much Milan It is  really a great code and working perfectly it was just some silly mistakes that i was doing , thank you for helping me you are such an humble person :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is flagged for JSoup, but wouldn't it be more reliable to simply use Amazon's API for retrieving this data?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingCustomerReviews.html